# Getting Nil trying to decode json

Tags: swift

I'm trying to decode the Json from this URL(:

```
https://api.letsbuildthatapp.com/appstore/featured
```

from "Lets build that app tutorials"
This is the code I wrote:

```
import UIKit

class AppCategory: NSObject{
    var name: String?
    var apps: [App]?

    static func fetchedFeaturedApps(){
        let jsonUrlString = "https://api.letsbuildthatapp.com/appstore/featured"
        guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else {return}
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
            guard let data = data else {return}
            do{
                let featured = try JSONDecoder().decode(Featured.self, from: data)
            }catch{
                print(err)
            }
            }.resume()
    }
}

struct Featured: Decodable {
    var bannerCategory: Banner?
    var featuredCategories: [mCategory]?
}
struct Banner: Decodable {
    var name: String?
    var apps: [String]?
    var type: String?
}

struct mCategory: Decodable {
    var name: String?
    var apps: [App]?
    var type: String?
}

struct App: Decodable {
    var id: Int?
    var name: String?
    var category: String?
    var price: Float?
    var imageName: String?
}
```

I tried to follow the tutorial but It didn't work for me.
I always get nil while trying to decode the json from the url. I'm really new to this and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I know to decode the json properly I need to have Structs as same as the json (like an app array in category) but it still won't work.

EDIT: Should've mentioned, When I run it, the code goes into the catch block and printing "nil".

I tried printing the 'err' but this is all I get in the log:

```
2019-02-09 19:07:45.241000+0200 AppStore[2344:120273] [AXMediaCommon] Unable to look up screen scale
2019-02-09 19:07:45.241153+0200 AppStore[2344:120273] [AXMediaCommon] Unexpected physical screen orientation
2019-02-09 19:07:45.314112+0200 AppStore[2344:120273] [AXMediaCommon] Unable to look up screen scale
2019-02-09 19:07:45.319977+0200 AppStore[2344:120273] [AXMediaCommon] Unable to look up screen scale
2019-02-09 19:07:45.320189+0200 AppStore[2344:120273] [AXMediaCommon] Unexpected physical screen orientation
nil
```

Comment: How do you know it's nil? You print `featured`? Is there an error in the do/catch?

Comment: It's going into the catch and printing "nil". should've mentioned it. I will add now. sorry.

Comment: So there is an error since there is a print(err)? Would you mind showing what's printed? Because there are plenty of information in it.

Comment: I added the log to the OP, but I don't think this is helpful as it only says nil too..

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/54608364/1801544 answers, no, there was an error caught.

Comment: Thanks man, This is now working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

> typeMismatch(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "bannerCategory", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode String but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))

you need

```
struct Featured: Codable {
    let bannerCategory: BannerCategory
    let categories: [Category]
}

struct BannerCategory: Codable {
    let name: String
    let apps: [BannerCategoryApp]
    let type: String
}

struct BannerCategoryApp: Codable {
    let imageName: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case imageName = "ImageName"
    }
}

struct Category: Codable {
    let name: String
    let apps: [CategoryApp]
    let type: String
}

struct CategoryApp: Codable {
    let id: Int?
    let name, category: String?
    let price: Double?
    let imageName: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "Id"
        case name = "Name"
        case category = "Category"
        case price = "Price"
        case imageName = "ImageName"
    }
}
```

---

```
class AppCategory: NSObject{
    var name: String?
    var apps: [CategoryApp]?

    static func fetchedFeaturedApps(){
        let jsonUrlString = "https://api.letsbuildthatapp.com/appstore/featured"
        guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else {return}
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
            guard let data = data else {return}
            do{
                let featured = try JSONDecoder().decode(Featured.self, from: data)
                print(featured)
            }catch{
                print(error)
            }
            }.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: where you get nil , below you need a completion

Comment: It goes straight to the catch block.

Comment: please get rid of all your structs  and test with what in answer only

Comment: I tried to debug, this is the problem it writes: debugDescription String "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"Name\", intValue: nil) (\"Name\")."

Comment: I double checked I wrote everything correctly, with the order and naming from the URL but still happens

Comment: Well, Just checked again, and It's now working, I guess the problem was that in some of the apps in the JSON the price is nil as it a 'free app' so making the price in CategoryApp optional worked. Thanks!